# Check for a value from table 1 in table 2 on different servers

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am struggling with how to do this and the examples I have found seem overly complicated for what I need to accomplish.

I have two tables in separate databases on separate servers. I need to see if Server1,Db1, table1, column2  contains any values that are not in Server2,Db2, table1, column2?

I am not sure where to start?

With the help below, here is what I tried and I get the error:

```
The multi-part identifier "NET_TEST.dbo.Details" could not be bound.
```

Query:

```
Declare @RCaseNum nvarchar(30);
Declare @CurrentYear DateTime;
Declare @EventNumber nvarchar(30);
Declare @CaseNum nvarchar(30);
SET @EventNumber = [NET_TEST].[dbo].[Details]
SET @CaseNum = [SQLTEST10\SQLTEST10].[CASE_TEST].[dbo].Incident
SET @CurrentYear = YEAR(getdate());
SET @RCaseNum =  @CurrentYear + @EventNumber
SELECT @EventNumber
EXCEPT
SELECT @CaseNum
```

Comment: Which RDBMS? SQL Server?

Comment: `select column2  from db1.schema.table1 where not exists (select  column2  from db2.schema.table1)` will help in sql server.

Comment: @MarkSinkinson SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1):

`EXCEPT` or `NOT EXISTS` are your best choices. I wrote a bit about them [on this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83684/except-operator-vs-not-in/83687#83687).

An example of `EXCEPT`.

```
SELECT column2 FROM Db1.table1
EXCEPT
SELECT column2 FROM Db2.table1
```

In any case, beware of using `NOT IN`.

Comment: How do I reference the databases if they are on different servers?

Answer (score 0):

Using Left join is another option

```
    select * from 
    Db1.table1 A
    left join Db2.table1 B on A.column2 = B.column2
    where B.column2 is NULL
```